# I am randomly getting "ScriptTimeoutError" using protractor

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor, automated-tests

My test suite contains more than 200 test cases and often I get ScriptTimeoutError for few test cases. This error is random and is not specific to a particulat test cases. 
Please Note: allScriptsTimeout: 120000, is set in conf.js file

protractor version = 5.1.2

Please see the error log

```
   Failed: Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish after 120 seconds. This may be because the current page is not an Angular application. Please see the FAQ for more details: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#waiting-for-angular
    While waiting for element with locator - Locator: by.cssContainingText(".ng-binding", "My example").
    The following tasks were pending:
     - $http: https://api.example.com/api/exampleionUsers
  Stack:
    ScriptTimeoutError: asynchronous script timeout: result was not received in 120 seconds
      (Session info: chrome=59.0.3071.86)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
    Command duration or timeout: 120.07 seconds
    Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
    System info: host: 'LAPTOP-RNQ2JQBE', ip: '192.168.89.84', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
    Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233), userDataDir=C:\Users\NEXTGEN\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir15404_10872}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=59.0.3071.86, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
```

Comment: Nobody answers, so I´m posting [this link here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/117) that indicates to put this (  onPrepare: function() {
     browser.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(60000);
  },) into your protractor configuration file, hope it helps

Comment: @FooBar Please check the logs, it says it waited for 120 sec for asynchronous calls($https and $timeout) to complete. I am waiting for asynchronous script to get completed by setting allScriptsTimeout: 120000 in conf.js file

Comment: sorry, i cant help you with protractor, just tried to help. Modify those 60.000 to 180.000 and try, maybe sometimes you're consuming 123 seconds ;)